# Как добавить image с анимацией

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Нужно как-то изобразить в xaml подобную анимированную картинку, в обычном Image изображение статичное
https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/730/0069a31ee7292be2aae3969b57a261e06a57bdcc.png

Comment: MediaPlayer + mp4/wmv например https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-play-media-with-animations

Comment: png с анимацией - это APNG формат, вот по этому обозначению и ищите нужный контрол. Пока могу предложить [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053316/how-can-i-use-animated-png-in-uwp). Еще как вариант, можно попробовать конвертировать APNG в GIF и проиграть его при помощи например NuGet пакета `WpfAnimatedGif`.